# Error in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Can anyone check if there are errors in it. here my code, If there is any error in the code please tell me? I don't know how to fix the code Search.java.

in my RecyclerItemClickListener.java

```
public interface RecyclerItemClickListener {
void onItemClick(int position);   
}
```

My Adapter HierAdapter.java

```
public class HireAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HireAdapter.ViewHolder>{


private ArrayList<HireItem> TeacherItemList;

private Context context;
private RecyclerItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public HireAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HireItem> teacherItemList, RecyclerItemClickListener listener) {
    TeacherItemList = teacherItemList;
    context = c;
    itemClickListener = listener;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public final TextView nameText, subjectText,levelText ,cityText;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

         nameText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.result_name);
         subjectText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.result_subject);
         levelText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.result_level);
         cityText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.result_city);

    }
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_teachers,parent,false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rowView);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.nameText.setText(TeacherItemList.get(position).getResult_name());
    holder.subjectText.setText(TeacherItemList.get(position).getResult_subject());
    holder.levelText.setText(TeacherItemList.get(position).getResult_level());
    holder.cityText.setText(TeacherItemList.get(position).getResult_city());

    //Here it is simply write onItemClick listener here
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileTeaAdapter.class);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return TeacherItemList.size();
}}
```

Here Search.java, I wrote notes at each error. Because I did not know how to correct some codes to work with HireAdapter and RecyclerItemClickListener, can anyone solve the error?

```
public class Search extends Fragment implements RecyclerItemClickListener {

private Context context;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private List<HireItem> hireItem = new ArrayList<>();
HireAdapter mAdapter;
ImageView bt_search;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Spinner spinner_sort;

String key = "req_skill1";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search,container,false);

    //Getting FireBase Instance
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teachers");

    //Getting id of Views
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_places);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    //
    bt_search = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bt_search);
    spinner_sort = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_sort);
    setupSpinner();

    List<HireItem> hireItem = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new HireAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.list_item_teachers,hireItem); // error at (getContext(),R.layout.list_item_teachers,hireItem)

    bt_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(mAdapter != null){
                mAdapter.clear(); // error at .clear();
            }

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Searching Teachers");
            progressDialog.show();


            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teachers").orderByChild("subject").startAt(key).endAt(key + "~")
                    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            Teachers child = dataSnapshot.getValue(Teachers.class);
                            HireItem hireItem = new HireItem(child.teaname, child.city, child.subject, child.level, child.sex,child.mobile, child.qualification, child.skill1, child.experince, child.salary,child.age);
                            mAdapter.add(hireItem);  // error at .add
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            if(mAdapter == null){
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Match Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

            if(mAdapter == null){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Match Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);  // error at recyclerView

            }

        }
    });
    return view;
}
private void setupSpinner(){
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),R.array.array_teacher_sort,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner_sort.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner_sort.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            key = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_A))){
                key = "Math";
            }else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AA))){
                key = "computer";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AB))){
                key = "Biology";
            }

            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AD))){
                key = "Physics";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AXX))){
                key = "Holy Quran";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AZ))){
                key = "Chysics";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AS))){
                key = "English";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AQ))){
                key = "Arabic";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_ADD))){
                key = "Science";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AE))){
                key = "History";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AW))){
                key = "Geograpghy";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AR))){
                key = "Art education";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_AT))){
                key = "Family education";
            }
            else if(key.equals(getString(R.string.sort_aae))){
                key = "Religion";
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter.clear();  // error at .clear();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

} }
```

Comment: _what error_? do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: have you tried to run this code?

Comment: When this statement is executed `recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` `mAdapter` is `null`.

Comment: I don't think `RecyclerView.Adapter` has a `clear()` method and you don't seem to define one in the `HireAdapter` which means that you're probably getting a compiler error on these calls `mAdapter.clear()`.

Comment: please read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic], to increase your chance of getting answers to your questions!

Comment: have you tried to run this code? no,

Comment: what error? the Search.java don't work, I don't know why.                          do you have a stacktrace? I don't have a stacktrace

Comment: the error here   `mAdapter = new HireAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.list_item_teachers,hireItem);`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_teachers,parent,false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rowView);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.nameText.setText(TeacherItemList.get(position).getResult_name());
    holder.subjectText.setText(TeacherItemList.get(position).getResult_subject());
    holder.levelText.setText(TeacherItemList.get(position).getResult_level());
    holder.cityText.setText(TeacherItemList.get(position).getResult_city());

    //Here it is simply write onItemClick listener here
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileTeaAdapter.class);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Here you are setting `onClickListner` on the same view twice. The `Listener` set in the `onBindViewHolder` will override the `Listner` set in the `onCreateViewHolder` method.